# Implementing a central 'manager' class for instances of a specific type across multiple assemblies

Tags: c#, .net, caching, nested, assemblies

In our software, we sometimes use a specific class to cache combinations of keys and values to prevent repeated retrieval of the same values from the database. Because the number of cache implementations is increasing, I would like to centralize the management of all cache implementations and to generalize the implementation of the different cache classes.

Therefore, I created a generic 'Cache' class, which is a private nested class of a static CacheManager class. Because of the private nested Cache class, this class cannot be initiated by any other class than the CacheManager itself.

The reason why I want to use a cache manager is because I want to be able to flush all cashes and to fetch statistics for all caches without missing cache implementations that I'm not aware of (created by colleagues).

An ICache interface is used to expose the caches to code outside of the CacheManager class.

Simplified implementations:

Interface

```
// Interface for all available caches
    public interface ICache<TKey, TValue>
    {
        bool            StatisticsEnabled   { get; set; }
        KeyStatistics[] Statistics          { get; }

        // Set cache item (including update)
        void Set(TKey key, TValue item);

        // Get an item from the cache (return value indicates found / not found in cache)
        bool Get(TKey key, out TValue value);
    }
```

Data objects for statistics

```
    // Statistics per key in the cache (or requested from the cache)
    public class KeyStatistics
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int RequestCount { get; set; }
        public int HitCount { get; set; }
    }

    // Contains statistics per cache
    public class CacheStatistics
    {
        public string           Name        { get; set; }
        public KeyStatistics[]  Statistics  { get; set; } 
    }
```

Static cache manager including generic cache implementation

```
    public static class CacheManager 
    {
        private static Lazy<Cache<string, string>> _settingsCache = new Lazy<Cache<string, string>>();
        private static Lazy<Cache<DateTime, short>> _mechanicCountCache = new Lazy<Cache<DateTime, short>>();

        // actual supported caches
        public static ICache<string, string> SettingsCache { get { return _settingsCache.Value; } }
        public static ICache<DateTime, short> MechanicCountCache { get { return _mechanicCountCache.Value; } }

        public static IEnumerable<CacheStatistics> Statistics
        {
            get 
            {
                yield return new CacheStatistics
                {
                    Name        = "Settings cache",
                    Statistics  = _settingsCache.Value.Statistics
                };
                yield return new CacheStatistics
                {
                    Name        = "Mechanics count cache",
                    Statistics = _mechanicCountCache.Value.Statistics
                };
            }
        }

        // Private class, so it cannot be initiated by anything else than the cache manager
        private class Cache<TKey, TValue> : ICache<TKey, TValue>
        {
            private ConcurrentDictionary<TKey, KeyStatistics> _statistics = new ConcurrentDictionary<TKey, KeyStatistics>();
            private ConcurrentDictionary<TKey, TValue> _cachedValues = new ConcurrentDictionary<TKey, TValue>();

            // Constructor
            public Cache() 
            {
                // Do some constructing things  
            }

            #region ICache
            public bool StatisticsEnabled { get; set; }

            public KeyStatistics[] Statistics
            {
                get { return _statistics.Values.ToArray(); }    
            }

            public void Set(TKey key, TValue item) 
            {
                // Todo: add to cache or update existing value

            }

            public bool Get(TKey key, out TValue item) 
            {
                // Todo: fetch from dictionary
                // Todo: update statistics

                item = default(TValue);
                return false;
            }

            #endregion ICache
        }
```

This will work as required. However, there is something that I haven't figured out yet. We work with multiple assemblies (core assemblies and 'specialized' assemblies). Specialized assemblies have a reference to core assemblies, but not the other way around.

I want the CacheManager (part of the core assembly) to be able to manage a cache with a TValue type from a specialized assembly. I want the cache to be visible only from the specialized assembly also. I know that I can't use partial classes and I don't think that Extensions will help me out either.

Is there a way to achieve what I want?

Comment: Not really, with your current setup; *core* needs to know *something* about the specialized types if its going to create an object based on them. Consider defining in *core*  one or several interfaces that the specialized types `TVaue` can implement. You can also consider the possibility of creating a third assembly *tools* implementing the cache manager (or only the interfaces) and have a reference to it in *core* and *specialized*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up with a cache manager in the core assembly. This cache manager doesn't know about the specialized cache types in referencing assemblies. Instead it has a 'GetCache()' method that is called using a generic type. The generic type must be an implementation of 'ICache'.

In the implementation of 'GetCache', the cache manager uses a generic 'Singleton' class that can create a singleton instance of a type (in this case the type that implements ICache).

[image]

Translation:
* GetStatistieken() > GetStatistics()
* Wissen() > Clear all cached contents

In the referencing assemblies, a cache instance can be fetched like this:

```
var cache = CacheManager.GetCache<DagCapaciteitCache>();
```

For ease of creation of a new cache, the cache instances can subclass one of the two cache base classes, but that is not required. The only requirement is that a cache implements the IQuery interface (defined in the core assembly).

Answer (score 1):

Bit late for the OP. For others, implementing a factory pattern could be the way to go. Reflection is then used to get all types implemented via the factory and iterated for resetting all/specific caches.

e.g.
https://www.dofactory.com/net/factory-method-design-pattern

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You could store only serialized object values in the cache manager itself.  It'd be up to the referencing assemblies to have the appropriate specialized assembly references.

Json.NET has worked well for me in the past for generic object serialization/deserialization.